# Funcionamento do método push

Tags: python, estrutura-de-dados, heap

No código:

```
import heapq

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._queue = []
        self._index = 0
    def push(self, item, priority):
        heapq.heappush(self._queue, (-priority, self._index, item))
        self._index += 1

class Person:

        def __init__(self,name):
            self.name = name

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.name

lista = PriorityQueue()
lista.push(Person('Dener'), 30)
lista.push(Person('Rodrigo'), 25)
lista.push(Person('Lucas'), 22)
```

Não entendi muito bem como funciona o método:

```
def push(self, item, priority):
        heapq.heappush(self._queue, (-priority, self._index, item))
        self._index += 1
```

Alguém poderia me explicar?

Comment: Me parece que está  faltando um `)` em algum lugar.

Comment: Já editei  @Lacobus

Comment: @LucasMoraes você poderia me explicar se o seu código roda e você só quer uma ajuda para entender o método, ou o código apresenta algum erro

Answer (score 0):

Esse método `push` armazena o item no atributo queue de acordo com o priority, do menor para o maior, e armazena a quantidade de elementos do array no atributo `_index`. Se quiser entender melhor como funciona a classe heapq, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html).